# Javascript style not overwriting css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple HTML drawer that contains product recommendations. Javascript is used to toggle it open and close. In the HTML, there are 2 prices, the regular price and the discounted price. Both are visible on load. The JS is supposed to hide the discounted price(current price), if the current price is the same as the old price. Because then it's not necessary to show both(identical prices). But if there is an offer, it's supposed to show both.

The problem is, my javascript for opening and closing the drawer is working, but the code for hiding/showing both prices aren't. And I know the code is fine because it works on another product recommendation template I'm using(which isn't a drawer, but normal on-page element).

I've tried putting the price-code before the drawer-function code, but then the drawer doesn't respond to clicks and does not open anymore.
When I use Preview in the software I'm using to inject product recommendations(Dynamic Yield), the prices are shown correctly. It's only when I preview it on the website itself, that it doesn't work. Both prices are shown even if they match.

Here  is the JS:

```
(function() {
    var container = document.querySelectorAll('.dy-sliding-drawer-container')[0];
  var handler = container.querySelector('.dy-sliding-handle');
  function toggle() {
    if (container.className.indexOf('dy-open') > -1) {
      container.className = container.className.replace('dy-open','');
    } else {
      container.className = container.className.trim() + ' dy-open';
    }
  }
  handler.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    toggle();
  });
})();

var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 599px)" );
var itemPrices = document.querySelectorAll('.price-box');
for(var i=0; i<itemPrices.length; i++){

   var discount_price_element = itemPrices[i].getElementsByClassName("dynamic-price")[0];
   var price_element = itemPrices[i].getElementsByClassName("regular-price")[0];
   
   if(parseFloat(discount_price_element.innerHTML) == parseFloat(price_element.innerHTML)){
     discount_price_element.style.display = "none";
     
    if (mq.matches) {
    price_element.style.fontSize = "16px";
    price_element.style.paddingTop = "15px";
      } else {
    price_element.style.fontSize = "20px";
    }
    
     price_element.style.fontWeight = "700";
   } else {
     price_element.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
     price_element.style.paddingLeft = "10px";
   }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to make both codes work together? I've tried putting them in the same function, with no luck.

Here is the HTML(I guess the only relevant code here is the `.price-box` div, but I'm gonna paste everything in case you need it):

```
<div>
  <div class="dy-sliding-drawer-container" data-dy-strategy-container="">
    <div class="dy-sliding-handle">
      <div class="dy-sliding-handle-text">
        ${Title}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dy-sliding-items-container dy-open">
      ${#Recommendation}
      <a href="${Item Link}" class="dy-rv-rcom-item">
        <div class="dy-rv-rcom-item-image-container item-${SKU}" style="  background-image: url(${Item Image}); background-size: cover;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover; 
            -o-background-size: cover;min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;">
        </div>
        <div class="dy-rv-rcom-item-name">${Item Name}</div>
        <div class="dy-rv-rcom-item-price">
          <div class="price-box">
            <span class="dynamic-price">${product_price_dynamic},-</span>
            <span class="regular-price">${price},-</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- button -->
        <div class="product-item-actions add-to-cart-button-dy">
          <div class="actions-primary">
            <form data-role="tocart-form" action="https://www.norli.no/checkout/cart/add/uenc/${uenc}/product/${product_id}/" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="product" value="${product_id}" tabindex="0">
              <input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="${uenc}" tabindex="0">
              <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="${formkey}" tabindex="0">
              <button type="submit" title="Handlekurv" class="action tocart primary" tabindex="0">
                <span class="tocart--short">Legg til</span>
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product actions product-item-actions read-more-button-dy" style="display: none !important;">
          <div class="actions-primary">
            <div class="fieldset">
              <div class="actions">
                <span class="out-of-stock-view-more lesmer-button" style="color:#FFF; display: none !important;">Les mer</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- button end -->
        
      </a>
      ${/Recommendation}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if the CSS is needed, heres is the CSS for the relevant classes(old price and new price:

```
.price-box{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.dynamic-price{
  color:#dd1768;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:700;
  letter-spacing:-1.5px !important;
  padding-bottom:0px !important;
  margin-bottom:0px !important;
}

.regular-price{
  font-size:14px;
  letter-spacing:-1px !important;
  padding-bottom:0px !important;
  margin-bottom:0px !important;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Could anybody help me out? Keep in mind that the Javascript works fine for recommendation widgets which loads on-page, but not with this click-to-open drawer. Appreciate any help.

Comment: It would help if you could publish the generated HTML, as it is received in the browser ("show page source"). Your markup still contains variables that will be replaced by actual values in your templating engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script **does basically work** - provided the variables in your template have been
replaced by actual values before the markup is rendered into the DOM. I have modified your data a little bit to demonstrate the correct behaviour on some same-price and some differing-price `.price-box` examples.

I also took the liberty of shortening your very verbose scripts. I have probably gone a bit too far, especially my `.reduce()` construct is *not* easy to read. But look at it as an extreme way of avoiding creating variable names.

```js
(function(){
  var container = document.querySelector('.dy-sliding-drawer-container');
  container.querySelector('.dy-sliding-handle').onclick=e=>
   container.classList.toggle("dy-open");
})();

// var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 599px)" );
document.querySelectorAll('.price-box').forEach(p=>{
 [...p.querySelectorAll("span")].reduce((a,c)=>a.style.display=(a.textContent==c.textContent?"none":""))});
```

```css
.dy-open {background-color:yellow}
.price-box{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.dynamic-price{
  color:#dd1768;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:700;
  letter-spacing:-1.5px !important;
  padding-bottom:0px !important;
  margin-bottom:0px !important;
}

.regular-price{
  font-size:14px;
  letter-spacing:-1px !important;
  padding-bottom:0px !important;
  margin-bottom:0px !important;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="dy-sliding-drawer-container" data-dy-strategy-container="">
<div class="dy-sliding-handle">
  <div class="dy-sliding-handle-text">
    ${Title}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dy-sliding-items-container">
  ${#Recommendation}
  <a href="#${Item Link}" class="dy-rv-rcom-item">
    <div class="dy-rv-rcom-item-image-container item-${SKU}" style="  background-image: url(${Item Image}); background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover; 
        -o-background-size: cover;min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;">
    </div>
    <div class="dy-rv-rcom-item-name">${Item Name}</div>
    <div class="dy-rv-rcom-item-price">
      <div class="price-box">
        <span class="dynamic-price">50,-</span>
        <span class="regular-price">50,-</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dy-rv-rcom-item-name">${Item Name}</div>
    <div class="dy-rv-rcom-item-price">
      <div class="price-box">
       <span class="dynamic-price">50,-</span>
       <span class="regular-price">60,-</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dy-rv-rcom-item-name">${Item Name}</div>
    <div class="dy-rv-rcom-item-price">
      <div class="price-box">
       <span class="dynamic-price">60,-</span>
       <span class="regular-price">60,-</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- button -->
    <div class="product-item-actions add-to-cart-button-dy">
      <div class="actions-primary">
        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="https://www.norli.no/checkout/cart/add/uenc/${uenc}/product/${product_id}/" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="product" value="${product_id}" tabindex="0">
          <input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="${uenc}" tabindex="0">
          <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="${formkey}" tabindex="0">
          <button type="submit" title="Handlekurv" class="action tocart primary" tabindex="0">
            <span class="tocart--short">Legg til</span>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product actions product-item-actions read-more-button-dy" style="display: none !important;">
      <div class="actions-primary">
        <div class="fieldset">
          <div class="actions">
            <span class="out-of-stock-view-more lesmer-button" style="color:#FFF; display: none !important;">Les mer</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- button end -->
    
  </a>
  ${/Recommendation}
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Explanation:

The `.reduce()` over all the `<span>`s in a `.price-box` div relies on the fact that the "reduced price" span always comes before the "regular price" one and that you will always have exactly two elements. When `reduce()` is called without the second (starting value) argument it takes the first array element (the "reduced price" span) as the starting value (`a`). The (only) "current" value in the iteration (`c`) will then be the regular price span. When the `.textContent` of both elements are the same the `a` span will be hidden, otherwise it will remain visible.

Comment: Thank you for you time. I tried this, and it's working just like the code I currently have. It opens and all but both prices are still visible when they're alike. I can confirm your code is working like mine because in preview(viewing it in the software), the price is hidden if it's alike. But when I view it on the website, the last part of the JS code is not loaded at all. I even tried with setTimeout on the last part of the JS, nothing.

Comment: It seems to me that the template action, i. e. the replacement of your variables for actual values happens *after* the JavaScript action. This would explain, why the regular and the reduced prices would always appear different and would therefore always be shown. You should find a way to trigger the JavaScript action *after* the prices have been filled in.

Comment: I just tried to replace the variables with "50" on both divs, still does not work. I think the second part of the code is being blocked from running, when I use that code on another template without the open function, it works as intended. I placed a console.log message inside the second js code, it's not logging anything in console. First one is. Any idea what to do? :/ but thanks for cleaning up the code for the drawer, that's useful.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and mark this as a correct answer, because the code you provided does work, I think the fault is from the software I'm injecting the code from. Thank you for your help.